# Is there a way to get rid of "Select Classes To Import" popup in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I use PhpStorm 2019.1.

I cut and pasted a method from one class to another in PhpStorm.
I got popup "Select Classes To Import".

Is there a way to turn it off? I just want to paste code, that's all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, review your settings on the

**File `==>` Settings `==>` Editor `-->` General `-->` Auto Import `::` PHP**

section.

Check the value of `Insert imports on paste`.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I thought I did,but I left `Insert imports on paste:` select   with value `ask`